# Easy way to remove tile concrete from bathroom wall?

Tags: bathroom, concrete, tile

Are there an easy to to remove tile concrete from the wall?

Are there e.g. some way to get it off in whole pieces so cleaning up afterwards will be easier?

Here is a picture of the wall in question. The tile concrete is about 2cm thick.

[image]

Comment: use dynamite and shape charges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, no.  It's a dirty, dusty, hard job.

I have used a 7 1/2inch circular saw fitted with a diamond blade.  Shop vac, dust mask, fan in window (box fan fitted with furnace filter does wonders)

I set the depth of the cut to be just the thickness of the mortar and try to cut vertically along each stud.  Depending on your helpers back strength, I'll cut horizontally at 2 to 3 foot intervals.

Pry each panel off (large crowbars or flatbars) usually its held together with a metal lath (wood in older homes, pre 1940s).  Watch your toes, each piece will be 20-30 lbs.

PS leave the first row removed laying on the floor. It will absorb the fall of any dropped pieces... Nails holding the lath will act like hinges then let go at inopportune moments.

Comment: +1 cut it out with circular saw.  To help the dust, I have a second person use the shop vac and keep it running with the hose right behind the saw.  Cuts the dust down a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a angle grinder with a masonry blade on that. I would prefer that over a circular saw, but it will probably be a little slower.

Comment: I do use said angle grinder, usually with a segmented diamond blade, as a close quarters tool, after the circular saw.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be dirty or dusty.  Whack it with a good hammer...  Make your strikes a few inches away and make straight lines going down so that you can pull out 8-10 inch strips of the concrete.  It isn't for everyone but takes about the same amount of time - although more man-power.