# How to remove tiles from wall?

Tags: tile

I have a wall in my house with tiles on it. I would like to remove the tiles but am not sure how to do that correctly. I see from other posts that this kind of thing seems to be a more difficult job. Does this advice apply in my case? The wall behind is made of drywall. This is an accent wall, not a fireplace.

It seems as if I may be able to pry the tiles off the wall. [Easy way to remove tile concrete from bathroom wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30528/easy-way-to-remove-tile-concrete-from-bathroom-wall)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this part of a fireplace? Or just an accent wall. If concrete it can be easy with a wide chisel and heavy hammer or if you have an air compressors purchase a pneumatic chisel, some come with 3 bits for less than 50 and can zip those off like butter.

Comment: What is the wall behind made of? If it is drywall, you will most likely ruin it when the stone tiles are removed.

Comment: @Mattman944 the wall behind is drywall

Comment: @EdBeal it is just an accent wall

Comment: The link you have is for a concrete wall, my original comment was how I do them with an air chisel. In this case with Sheetrock put down a tarp and a heavy framing hammer and I could have the wall down in under an hour in most cases but the clean up would take longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the wall behind the tiles being drywall you would be wise go rip the tiles and drywall down

Removing the tiles will tear the paper and possibly take chunks of the gypsum out. Even going very slow and trying the Sheetrock will be heavily damaged.

I would rip the tile down with the Sheetrock, we can’t tell how wide the wall is but it will be much faster to demo and replace.